# Abnormal speech result

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, text-to-speech

I am trying to use MS TTS technology in C#. I am using MS visual studio 2010 professional, and I am in Windows 7 ultimate 32 bit.

Following is my code

```
SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
s.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male);
s.Speak("what is happening right now?");
```

When I run this code, the only thing I can hear is "bla bla bla". It is actually resulting "bla bla bla" sound, no words. If I remove the second line, I can hear the speak in default female voice. What is wrong here?

Comment: The part when you stated ` can hear is "bla bla bla". It is really "bla bla bla"` is quite vague and intrusive to intelligence. Could you maybe edit it to 'actual' results. Also, maybe that voice has an error?

Comment: @NewAmbition: I don't know whether there is a voice error. It got no other voice options to select as well.

Comment: The documentation says something like: `Use the GetInstalledVoices method and VoiceInfo class to obtain the names of installed text-to-speech (TTS) voices that you can select. The SpeechSynthesizer object selects the first installed voice whose Gender property matches the gender parameter.` Maybe you should try this ? The default Male voice may have a problem.

Comment: I have the same problem here, I think the default male english voice has a serious problem of "Bla Bla Bla" maybe it is a vampire voice ?